# Live audio via socket.io 1.0

Tags: html, node.js, sockets, audio, stream

As from socket.io website

> ### Binary streaming
>
> Starting in 1.0, it's possible to send any blob back and forth: image, audio, video.

I'm now wondering, if this couldn't be the solution for something I'm trying to achieve recently.

I'm actually looking for a way how to broadcast live audio stream from (A - ie, mic input..) to all clients connected to a website of mine. Is something like this possible? I've been messing with WebRTC (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/) examples but I haven't been able to manage the goal for more than few connected clients.

My idea is about something like getUserMedia or any other audio source (PCM, whatever..) on side A being chopped to chunks and provided to client and played for example by html5 audio element or anything.. I need to make that stream as much realtime as possible, no shout/ice cast services werent fast enough (indeed, they arent solution to my problem, they're meant to be used this way) and I don't really care about the audio quality. Crossplatform compatibility would be awesome.

Is something like that possible? By using socket.io as way how to provide those data to clients?

I would be very grateful for any reference, hint or source that could help me achieve this.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

This example shows you how to use the `MediaRecorder` to upload audio and then forward it using `socket.io`. This code will only broadcast after you're called `mediaRecorder.stop()`. You can choose to broadcast inside of `ondataavailable`. If you do that, you might want to pass a `timeslice` to `mediaRecorder.start()`, so that it doesn't trigger `ondataavailable` so often.

This solution isn't truly live, but I think it will help people who come back and find this question.

**Client Code**

```
var constraints = { audio: true };
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream) {
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
    mediaRecorder.onstart = function(e) {
        this.chunks = [];
    };
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        this.chunks.push(e.data);
    };
    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
        var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
        socket.emit('radio', blob);
    };

    // Start recording
    mediaRecorder.start();

    // Stop recording after 5 seconds and broadcast it to server
    setTimeout(function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop()
    }, 5000);
});

// When the client receives a voice message it will play the sound
socket.on('voice', function(arrayBuffer) {
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    audio.play();
});
```

**Server Code**

```
socket.on('radio', function(blob) {
    // can choose to broadcast it to whoever you want
    socket.broadcast.emit('voice', blob);
});
```

Comment: Hey your code is working fine but it is stop after 5 second because of setTimeout function after that other client can listen . Is This any way to do other client listen all voice in every neon second?

Comment: Hey @niteshsingh, I'm not exactly sure how to do it off the top of my head without messing around with the code. I don't know when I'll get back to modifying this though but hopefully this helps you get the basics setup! Let me know if you figure it out :)

Answer (score 2):

In the **Client Code** you can write **setInterval()** instead of setTimeout() and then recursively call **mediaRecorder.start()** so that every 5 seconds the blob will be emitted continuously.

```
setInterval(function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop()
        mediaRecorder.start()
    }, 5000);
```

**Client Code**

```
var constraints = { audio: true };
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream) {
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
mediaRecorder.onstart = function(e) {
    this.chunks = [];
};
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    this.chunks.push(e.data);
};
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
    var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
    socket.emit('radio', blob);
};

// Start recording
mediaRecorder.start();

// Stop recording after 5 seconds and broadcast it to server
setInterval(function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop()
    mediaRecorder.start()
  }, 5000);
});

// When the client receives a voice message it will play the sound
socket.on('voice', function(arrayBuffer) {
  var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio.play();
});
```

**Server Code**

```
socket.on('voice', function(blob) {
    // can choose to broadcast it to whoever you want
    socket.broadcast.emit('voice', blob);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do it not every 5 seconds but in real time? like 1ms?

Comment: How can i read this blob after in Java? It looks like a ebml file